# Android: Firing intents from a view

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, android-intent

I have an activity with a custom view which extends `EditText` in it. Usually when someone longclicks an EditView a `menu pops up` asking the user to choose input method.

I have *overridden* the `onLongClick` to **make this menu NOT appear**, since 
I use my own methods of input. However, i want a `ListActivity` to start when user longclicks the `EditText` (or rather again my view which extends EditText). **But it seems a view cannot fire intents, only activities, am i right?**

Fine, so i try to capture the longclick from the activity that spawned my EditText-like view. But inside my EditText-like view i already consume the longclick, either in the overridden `onLongClick()` by setting it true to avoid the *"Please choose input method"* menu to appear, or if returning false, then that very menu appears and consumes my longclick. In neither of the cases the intent fires...

In short:
**A user longclicks an EditText, and i want a custom ListActivity to start. How do i accomplish this?**

**EDIT:**
So i found `startActivity` in the `Context object`. But i will have the user pick an item from a list. That item would then appear in the `EditText`, so i thought i had to use `startActivityForResult`, which incidentally does not appear in the `Context object` :(

**EDIT 2:**
How do i get a result back from an activity started with `startActivity`?

Comment: Thanks for the nice formatting of my question! I'm not very proficient in stackexchange formatting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an Activity to [start another Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), but a Context object.

You got two options here. You can either pass an context into you custom view by using a custom constructor or a setter method. Or the OnLongClickListener has to be implemented in the Activity and set to the custom EditText from there.

Comment: I'd like to go with option one, since i do store the context as a field in the view, and i think it is more logical to handle the logic in there since the `listActivity' so clearly belongs to the view. **So how do i do it?** _context.startActivityForResult() doesn't work...

Comment: What exactly happens? Have you passed the Context into you custom EditView class?

Comment: `public EqEditText(Context context) {
  super(context);
  this.setOnLongClickListener(this);
  _context = context;
 }`

Comment: I also have the other two constructors looking exactly the same... I found the `startActivity()` though...

Comment: Yes it does work, but i can't figure out how to get the result back... The result is a `String`.

Comment: Ah, I checked the docs. `startActivityForResult()` is not a method of the Context but of the Activity class. So change the constructor to take an Activity object instead of a Context object and you should be fine. But when I rethink the whole problem and you  implement a custom EditText only to override the onLongClick() method I would suggest to go with the second option of my initial answer as it seems to be much easier and cleaner.

Comment: If i change the constructor the view won't get inflated... I'll try option 2!